# react boilerplate - set up build to run from non-root directory

Tags: react-boilerplate

I asking how to configure [react boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate) to run from a non-root directory.

taking the standard release of react boilerplate:

```
# from directory www-root
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate.git rbp
cd rbp
npm run setup
npm build
```

when i navigate to http://localhost/rbp/build/index.html the files are there, but the chunks won't load because the paths are set to root.

I edited internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js:  added a key to module.exports for output.publicPath = '/rbp/build/'

This change results in the url http://localhost/rbp/build/index.html loading its chunks, but routing isn't working properly. The container loads, but the address bar to changes to http://localhost/features not to http://localhost/rbp/build/features

also entering http://localhost/rbp/build/features  into the address bar does not work.

I feel that there should be some sort or relative path setting somewhere, but i can't see it.  There is so much churn with versions in the javascript world it is hard for me know what is relevant or not.

So how can i get a url entered in the address bar to correctly load the index.html and route to the correct container?

Answer (score 0):

well it seems that behaviour is expected.  this post explains it very well . https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/8272354 . i elected to go for the simple hashHistory method.